# How to use ORDER BY and GROUP BY together in the same query

Tags: soql, filters, aggregate

I am trying to retrieve a list of LoginHistory for a bunch of users, but only want the most recent LoginHistory for each user.

I have been trying this query, but I keep getting an unknown parsing error

```
SELECT UserId, Status FROM LoginHistory WHERE UserId IN :userIds ORDER BY LoginTime DESC GROUP BY UserId
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

The equivalent query I am trying to construct is

```
for(Id userId : userIds){
    [SELECT status FROM LoginHistory WHERE UserId =:userId ORDER BY LoginTime LIMIT 1];
}
```

but I want to bulkify it with multiple userIds so I don't throw a too many soql queries error

Comment: Did you try reversing the order putting group by first?

Comment: Wont that order the UserIds and not the results then? @Eric

Comment: Um. Move the fields along with the keywords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must put `GROUP BY` before `ORDER BY`. Take a look at [SOQL SELECT Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm):

> **SELECT** *fieldList* [subquery][...]
>   [TYPEOF typeOfField whenExpression[...] elseExpression END][...]
>   **FROM** objectType[,...]
>       [USING SCOPE filterScope]
>   [**WHERE** conditionExpression]
>   [WITH [DATA CATEGORY] filteringExpression]
>   [**GROUP BY** {fieldGroupByList|ROLLUP (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)|CUBE (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)}
>       [HAVING havingConditionExpression] ]
>   [**ORDER BY** fieldOrderByList {ASC|DESC} [NULLS {FIRST|LAST}] ]
>   [LIMIT numberOfRowsToReturn]
>   [OFFSET numberOfRowsToSkip]
>   [FOR {VIEW  | REFERENCE}[,...] ]
>         [ UPDATE {TRACKING|VIEWSTAT}[,...] ]

Also note that you must group all fields you query for. Correct syntax:

```
SELECT UserId, Status
FROM LoginHistory
WHERE UserId IN :userIds
GROUP BY UserId, Status
ORDER BY LoginTime DESC
```

---

If you want to get the most recent `LoginHistory.Status` for each specified user, I don't think aggregates will help. Normally query row limits aren't a huge concern, so you can probably just pull in the last 30 days or some such and post-process them.

```
Map<Id, String> mostRecentStatus = new Map<Id, String>();
for (LoginHistory history : [
    SELECT Status, UserId
    FROM LoginHistory
    WHERE Id IN :userIds
    AND LoginTime >= LAST_N_DAYS:30
    ORDER BY LoginTime, UserId DESC
]){
    if (!mostRecentStatus.containsKey(history.UserId))
        mostRecentStatus.put(history.UserId, history.Status);
}
```

Comment: can i use latModifiedDate in the combination of group by and order by

Comment: Your first query gets me this `[object Object]: Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated: LoginTime
`

Comment: And then it turns out you can't even aggregate `LoginTime`... and then it turns out that order by just plain doesn't work after a group by. AT ALL.